# How can I view email in conversations view?

Tags: email

I am looking for a way to view my emails on Android in conversation style view, just like Gmail does. I've tried Aqua Mail, MailDroid, K-9 Mail and Kaiten Mail, but none seems to have a conversation view.

To be clear; I am not looking for a "Threaded view". A threaded view groups emails on the basis of subject, but does not include my own emails in that conversation. What I need is a way to view the emails as a conversation in which all emails, including my own, are listed.

Does anybody know how I would be able to view my emails on Android in conversation view?